# Windows cannot find network driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers, motherboard

I previously had Windows 10 x64 Educational as my host OS and everything was fine.

I decided to make the leap to make Ubuntu 18.04 LTS my host and everything was fine and dandy there as well.

After a day or so, I decided I wanted to dual boot *(purely for gamings sake)*. Tried to make Windows my host again *(as it is recommended Windows is the 1st installed)* and it cannot find some of the drivers that are located on the motherboard *(i.e. the network driver)*...

**NOTE:** Ubuntu can still find these drivers no problem and connect to the internet fine. I have also tried on Windows 7 and that still cannot find it/them.

When looking in `Device Manager`, I am greeted with this:

[image]

On the `properties` of the *Ethernet Controller*:

[image]

Things I have tried:

- Complete reset & fresh install of Windows 10 as recommended [here](https://www.tenforums.com/network-sharing/5906-no-network-adapter-detected.html#post235207)
 - Select to 'uninstall' the drivers, restart, and try and get Windows to re-find them from [here](https://appuals.com/network-adapter-not-detected-in-windows-10/) which is *Method 3* *(I also attempted 'Method 2' here but that was the same as the point above)*

This motherboard is MSI Z97-GD65 Gaming. Looking in the BIOS, all looks as it should with no errors.

Currently trying to download the required drivers on another machine and port them over but other than that I am not sure...

If anyone has any suggestions then please let me know :)

Comment: not sure if this would be of any significance but is it possible that Ubuntu requires different drivers to run your network card and when you installed and ran the Ubuntu OS the drivers were altered to work in compliance with Ubuntu? I would try getting back on the Ubuntu server and comparing what drivers are on it vs what drivers windows calls for, for that particular device. There may be a deadlock going on between the 2 OS's requiring 2 different drivers. Only reason I mention this is because Ubuntu may have required a different file format not recognizable by windows based OS's as well.

Comment: Sorry, @RickwhoPrograms, but Ubuntu is in an entirely different ext4  filesystem, and will not touch the Windows drivers in the NTFS filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I went onto my spare computer and downloaded all *(just to be safe)* drivers for my motherboard/OS pair.

The Killer Ethernet was the one that mattered. I then unzipped it on my comp and scanned for it in Device Manager. After that I was able to connect to the internet and from there Windows 10 apparently downloaded all other missing drivers without prompting :D

Comment: Yea, Windows can load lots of drivers AFTER it gets the network driver. If it doesn't have the network driver, it can't get anything until it does. Glad you were able to figure it out. This is a pretty normal part of any computer setup. It's less and less of an issue now, but especially if your network device is the driver missing, it still helps to know that you'll need the drivers on hand to get it past this point.

Answer (score -2):

You are experiencing what I've been fixing 2 years ago for around 3 months.

TL;DR: You're going towards the right direction generally, but it would get quite dangerous.

My way of fixing it would be to find another empty drive, install Windows on it, and it should allow you to install a proper Ethernet driver. You can also manually find the driver online which I don't think there are.

If you can, backup and uninstall your Ubuntu installation, install Windows first before installing Ubuntu back. I had a PC with Windows in it 3 years ago already and installed Ubuntu using an external USB HDD, there's no problem about it.

Comment: Note: if you are using a PC from a retail store, you might be able to find drivers on respective manufacturer, i.e. HP, Fujitsu, Lenovo, etc.

Download the driver on a USB drive and install it on your PC.

Comment: That's really jumping past a lot of the normal first-steps for driver troubleshooting. The first one being the one OP used to solve their problem: Download the driver and install it.

Comment: The problem is that it's a result of mixing Dual Boot OSes drivers together. That's why reinstalling Windows and Ubuntu all together is the best solution, to ensure all drivers are without conflicts, not just the Ethernet driver.

In the end I know some third party software but it may harm your computer, I'm personally a more conservative person on security so I didn't mention any.

Comment: But neither OS has anything to do with the other OS when it comes to drivers. They share disk space and the bootloader must be properly configured, but there is no reason to have to reinstall OSes in order to fix a missing driver. The problem was not that the system was dual-booted, it was that the NIC driver was not included in the base Windows install and so had to be manually found and loaded. The conservative thing to do is not rip-and-replace, it is to find the correct driver and load it: minimum effort, maximum effect.